# jQuery script not activating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made this jQuery script. Its purpose is to add a class to `<body>` when body is scrolled a certain amount. However nothing happens on scroll. DOM console doesnt show any error messages. I am a complete Javascript-newbie, so I would not be surprised if the problem is a simple markup mistake.
Any help is appreciated.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 if ((window.screen.width / window.screen.height) >= 1.33){
  $(document.body).on('scroll', function(e) {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $(document.body).addClass('fix');
    } else {
   $(document.body).removeClass('fix');
    }

  });
};
});
```

```css
body{
  height:200vh;
  background-color:blue;
 }
.fix{
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to listen to scroll event on `window`

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if ((window.screen.width / window.screen.height) >= 1.33) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('body').addClass('fix');
      } else {
        $('body').removeClass('fix');
      }

    });
  };
});
```